# C++ extern not found when in header

Tags: c++, header, extern, libjpeg

I am very new to C++ and I'm trying to do my best to have a good project structure from the beginning.
I am using the C library `libjpeg` and was including it in my `.cpp` with the use of

```
extern "C" {
  #include <jpeglib.h>
}
```

It worked fine until I removed it to put it in a header file which now gives me the following errors:

```
inc/jpeg_utils.h: 6: inc/jpeg_utils.h: extern: not found
inc/jpeg_utils.h: 8: inc/jpeg_utils.h: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

My header`jpeg_utils.h` :

```
#ifndef JPEG_UTILS_INCLUDE
#define JPEG_UTILS_INCLUDE
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" {
    #include <jpeglib.h>
}
int read_jpeg_file(char *filename, int decompression);
void write_jpeg_file(char *filename, unsigned char *image_buffer, int image_width, int image_height, int quality);
#endif
```

And at the top of `jpeg_utils.cpp` :

```
#include "../inc/jpeg_utils.h"
```

Did I misunderstand the use of a header ?

Comment: Does renaming the header to jpeg_utils.hpp change anything?

Comment: @Jovasa Why should changing the name of the file, make any difference?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include `jpeg_utils.h` in a C file, that `extern "C"` directive will not compile (obviously, C is not C++).

Add a pre-processor directive to `extern "C"` only when in fact you compile as C++.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    #include <jpeglib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: My project is in C++, only the jpeg library that I need is in C. It may be confusing that I used a `.h` and not a `.hpp` but I read that there is no differences. So unfortunately this solution doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @SarahHime - There's nothing confusing about the suffix. The error is indicative of the fact you included your header in a file that's compiled as pure C. Did you actually *try* this solution before deciding it doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: Of course I tried it, I still get the same error (I'm compiling with g++).

Comment: @SarahHime - [I took a look at the github page for a clone of `libjpeg`](https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg/blob/master/jpeglib.h). It already uses `extern "C"`, try removing your redundant ones and check if it helps

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the error ! I'm still curious about how it used to work in my `.cpp` file.

Comment: @SarahHime - No idea. Header inclusion is pure text substitution. If it couldn't work in a header, it shouldn't have worked when directly in the cpp file. Still, glad it was sorted out for you.